# Как проверить есть ли запись в отношении Laravel

Tags: laravel

Подскажите, ошибка `Property [contract_pays] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Как проверить есть ли запись в отношении `contract_pays`

```
$base = Base::find(55);

if ($base->contracts->contract_pays){
    return "OK";
}else{
    return "NO";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что обращeение к объекту `Collection` и попытка вызвать данное свойство у этого объекта.

`$base->contracts` - возвращяет коллекцию.

Если подразумевается, что у объекта `Сontract` есть свойство `contract_pays`,
то возможно нужно сделать следующее:

```
    $contract = $base->contracts->first();
    if ($contract && $contract->contract_pays) {
        return 'OK';
    } else {
        return 'NO';
    }
```

или работать со всем этим в цикле:

```
    foreach($base->contracts as $contract) {
        dump($contract->contract_pays);
    }
```